# jQuery get input value inside $(this) based on name

Tags: jquery

I want to get an input's value (name="id"), the input must be inside  $(this).

```
<form>
<input name="id" />
</form>
```

This is what I am trying right now:

```
$(this).("[name='id']").val
```

Comment: I thought of trying to get it from `$(this).serialize()` but I'm sure there must be an easy way

Comment: Did you try `$("[name='id']", this).val();`

Comment: `this` is totally relative. Could you give us the surrounding JS code of your line? That said, you should try `$(this).find('[name="id"]').val()`.

Answer (score 10):

If it has to be in `$(this)` as of parent, just do

```
$(this).find("[name='id']").val()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to traverse element descendants. Also note that, in general, you get better performance when you include the element type (e.g. `input`) in the attribute-equals selector:

```
$(this).find("input[name='id']").val();
```

Comment: Lets try that out in [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/tags) ??? On the other hand if there where many elements, it could possibly be faster to filter by tagname.

Comment: @adeneo interesting result, but with that tiny test case I don't think it's statistically significant. The idea is that omitting the tag name is equivalent to doing `*[name='id']`, which would have to check each element for the attribute as opposed to just `<input>` elements. Sadly I can't find the jQuery/sizzle doc source for this claim, so hopefully this is accurate, but as soon as I do I'll post it here :)

Comment: Just throw a bunch of other crap in there, and filtering by tagname is faster [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/tags), but that's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @adeneo It is somewhat relevant since, for one, the code in the question seems to be a small, simple test case -- the full code may be much longer/more complex; and two, it is simply 'best *(better?)* practice' -- so as a general rule that is the style that should be advocated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var $selectedInput = $("input[name=id]");

    if($selectedInput.length > 0){
//element is available

    alert($selectedInput.val());

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

you can simply do it like this

```
$("[name='id']").val()​;
```

​[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cjqed/)

Comment: It's not inside the `this` context, as explicitly stated in the question.

Comment: what is the need of that if it is directly accessible

Comment: @rahul Well for one the `name` attribute is not unique, so your selector could be matching any number of elements not shown in OP's html fragment...

Comment: i just made it according to provided html